# HIghcharts Common spacing at yaxis in Dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am displaying a area spline dynamic data graph where the dynamic values are fetching from a particular API. The problem is, when the dynamic data are displaying, the graph series goes below the y-axis or above the graph's customized design.

From my side, I found that the problem is with y-axis spacing. So, my question is: could I use a common spacing at y-axis? And the series must display above a particular pixels (height) from x-axis. At the same time, I can use the options min, max, tickinterval because of changing the data from external source.

Here is my y-axis,

```
yAxis: {
    title: {  
        text: '',
    },
    opposite: true,
    offset: 0,
    crosshair: {
        color: '#335A81',
        label: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{value:.5f}'
        }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0.1,
    labels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        x: 10,
        format: '{value: .5f}'
    },
    opposite: true,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you described here and what the common spacing is. You have set min and max, and your data is not shown if it have below/above values? Read about softMin/softMax and minPadding/maxPadding http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMax

Comment: Look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPixelInterval and/or http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount